# IndexOutOfBoundsException (@ArrayList:throwIndexOutOfBoundsException:251) {main}

Tags: android, exception, google-analytics

I have an android app that throws the following exception:

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException (@ArrayList:throwIndexOutOfBoundsException:251) {main}
```

This is only shown in Google Analytics for the app and I cannot reproduce it on any of the developer's devices. The class reported is ArrayList (Java) and not part of my app so I have difficulty in figuring out where the exception is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics isn't really going to be as helpful as a full featured crash reporting system like Bugsense, Crittercism, or just plain ACRA. [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) is a free 3rd party library that sets itself up as the exception handler much like you have Google Analytics set up here, but generates full stack traces, allows you to set custom data (user ID, phone model, etc) that will help you be able to more fully understand the crash. You can then set up a free account at [Bugsense](http://www.bugsense.com/) to catch these reports and provide all the data contained in them, as well as email alerts for when new crashes happen.

Comment: One thing to note, if you do set this up, is that you'll want to make sure to turn off exception handling in GoogleAnalytics, so it's not fighting ACRA for that role.